# Landscape and page numbers with pdfpages

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages, landscape

I am using `pdfpages` to insert PDFs into a master file. Some of the PDFs are portrait and some are landscape. I am using `pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}` so that the page numbers are in sequence throughout the final document. However, on PDFs included as landscape, the page numbers appear on the left side of the page (i.e. as they would if the page were not landscape). How can I get them to appear on the bottom of the page?

MWE where `one.pdf` is included in portrait and `two.pdf` is included in landscape:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

This is the text in the master file.

\newpage{}

\includepdf[pages=-,landscape=false]{one}

\newpage{}

\includepdf[pages=-,landscape=true]{two}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: For pdflscape, see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278113/single-landscape-page-with-page-number-at-the-bottom

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) you can define your own page style and move the page number/counter into the appropriate position.

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancypagestyle{mylandscape}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot{% Footer
    \makebox[\textwidth][r]{% Right
      \rlap{\hspace{\footskip}% Push out of margin by \footskip
        \smash{% Remove vertical height
          \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\baselineskip+\footskip+.5\textheight}{% Raise vertically
            \rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}}}% Rotate counter-clockwise
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}
```

You would then use `pagecommand=\thispagestyle{mylandscape}`. Example output with `one.pdf` (1 page portrait) and `two.pdf` (1 page landscape):

[image]

#### `two.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

#### `one.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,pdfpages,fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,pdfpages,fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{mylandscape}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot{% Footer
    \makebox[\textwidth][r]{% Right
      \rlap{\hspace{\footskip}% Push out of margin by \footskip
        \smash{% Remove vertical height
          \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\baselineskip+\footskip+.5\textheight}{% Raise vertically
            \rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}}}% Rotate counter-clockwise
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\includepdf[noautoscale,landscape,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{mylandscape}]{two.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution isn't working for me.  Could you show us how the mylandscape command was included on the page?  I am using pdflscape package and begin/end{landscape} to rotate my pages.  The solution you have proposed places the page number in bold towards left of the page, not center.

Comment: @cryptic0: I've added the MWE that creates the image in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response and the code.  What is the function of `two.pdf`?

Comment: @cryptic0: The OP mentioned a separate document which was set in landscape format. In my case, I created a dummy document `two.tex` which, when compiled with `pdflatex`, creates `two.pdf`.

Comment: What if I didn't want that.  Could I then just use `\thispagestyle{mylandscape}`?

Comment: @cryptic0 It seems to work for me just using it in a single document setting.

Comment: works great, the part with the `% Raise vertical` comment actually controls the location on the bottom of the landscape page. I needed a quite specific location and used `\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\baselineskip+\footskip+.65\textheight`