# Page number position on a single landscape page

Tags: positioning, page-numbering, landscape

I tried the solution mentioned in the thread by John Kormylo:

[single landscape page with page number at the bottom?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278113/single-landscape-page-with-page-number-at-the-bottom/278169)

While successfully placing a page number at the bottom of the landscape page, the original page number on the left hand side is still there. Sorry that I am opening a new post for this question, I just registered and cannot comment...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That is what the \pagestyle{empty} is for.